# SWI-Prolog 7.2.3 has library on one machine but not another

Tags: prolog, windows-10, swi-prolog, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bash-on-windows

I am developing Prolog code and using SWI-Prolog on two different machines. Both SWI-Prolog installations are on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows 10.

I don't remember the steps I followed to install SWI-Prolog on the first machine, but it runs code requiring `library(plunit)` without a hitch.
Running `swipl --version` on the console returns

```
SWI-Prolog version 7.2.3 for amd64
```

On the second machine, on which I downloaded and made/installed [from source](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl/releases/tag/V7.2.3), I get an ERROR saying `source_sink 'library(plunit)' does not exist`. Running `swipl --version` on the console returns

```
SWI-Prolog version 7.2.3 for x86_64-linux
```

My understanding was that libraries for SWI-Prolog were release-dependent. Is that not the case? Perhaps the `swipl --version` values provide some insight? Unfortunately, I am stuck with this specific version of SWI-Prolog for compatibility reasons. So far my attempts to reinstall `swipl` on the second machine have been fruitless.